# How do I make landscape cocos2d v2.0 games on ios6?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, landscape

I had been working on a couple of games from a few months back.  I migrated them to cocos2d v2.0 just fine but yesterday I tried creating a new one and I get it only in portrait no matter what I do to the Target settings rotations.

How can I make my new game landscape?

Answer (score 0):

Search for supportedInterfaceOrientations function in AppDelegate class and change it to landscape. If this function not found then add it.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations 
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Comment: There is no such method, the closest is `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
 return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}` and adding the one you suggested doesnt make it work either :(

Comment: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation  is for iOS5 and below..in iOS6  its supportedInterfaceOrientations.

Comment: Yes I know, but I did what you suggested and it doesnt fix it.

Comment: in xcode summary page also u set landscape? why can't you update sdk to cocos2d 2.1? or just download and see code in appDelegate and copy :-

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it by changing the addSubview line:

```
[window_ addSubview:navController_.view];
```

to

```
[window_ setRootViewController:navController_];
```

wonder why